# border radius in react native not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I made an app in react native expo. So I applied border radius to one of the `<View>` in it. So my problem is most of the phones shows the border radius in app But some phones are showing it rectangular `<View>` as it is, they are not showing border radius to them. Why?

my Code:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity ,Image, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import ButtonsCom from '../../components/buttonsCom';
import NavBar2 from '../../components/navBar2';


const animals3=function ({navigation}){

    
    return <View >   

                 <NavBar2 />

                <View style={style.styleView456}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{}} activeOpacity={0.8}  onPress={()=>{}}> 
                                    <View  style={style.styleView}>
                                        
                                        <View style={style.styleView888}>
                                            <View style={style.styleView8882}>
                                                <Image style={style.imageVio888} source={require('../../../assets/animals/elephant.png')}/>
                                                <Text style={{marginTop:100, marginHorizontal:10 , fontSize:20, fontWeight:"bold"}}>ELEPHANT</Text>
                                            </View>

                                    
                                        </View>
                                    </View>     
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        

                        <View style={style.styleView}>
                            <ButtonsCom/>                        </View>
                </View>
    </View> 

}
let ScreenHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height-90;
const style=StyleSheet.create({
    styleView456:{
        height:ScreenHeight,
        justifyContent:"space-around"
    },
    styleView:{
        flexDirection:"row",
        justifyContent:"space-around",
        paddingTop:20
    },
    styleView888:{
        borderColor:"#F5F6FA",
        width:300,
        height:500,
        borderRadius:20,
        alignItems:"center",
        shadowColor:'black',
        shadowOffset:{ width: 0, height: 3 }, 
        shadowRadius:6,
        elevation:5
        
    },
    imageVio888:{
        
        width:270,
        height:200,
        marginTop:60
    },
    styleView8882:{
        alignItems:"center"
    }
 });
 
 
 export default animals3;
```

So, I have applied border radius to **style=style.styleView888**

Comment: What the same phones not show border radius?

Comment: i installed apk of the app on 4 different android phones. But 1 phone not showing that border radius and others 3 are showing

Comment: Please write model phone.

Comment: its not working on redmi note 8 pro

Comment: Please show code with layout and styles

Comment: i edited the above question

Comment: Can you try remove shadow/elevation?

Comment: ya, now its working by removing shadow / elevation and applying border=black, borderWidth=3,

Comment: It's React Native bug.

Elevation and border radius do not work well with opacity from Android 9
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25093

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's React Native bug

[Elevation and border radius do not work well with opacity from Android 9](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25093)

Answer (score 15):

According to docs, you might need to apply `overflow: 'hidden'` .

https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props

Comment: i did that change but it still not working on some devices

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue in React Native on Android devices and applying `overflow: 'hidden` as well as `background: 'transparent'` fixes the issue. No idea why the background colour is required but it works!

Answer (score 0):

> Al last Solved

I was facing an issue that when I gave the border-radius to the card used in flatlist then border-radius was not working in android but working properly in ios. The only thing I do was ***background: 'transparent'*** added in the card parent container style.

```
container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginTop: isIos ? HP(1.1) : HP(1.5),
    borderRadius: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: theme.dark.dark6,
    padding: isIos ? HP(1.6) : HP(2),
  +  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
```